# How do continue a pattern or style if it is in bitmap form?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns

I have downloaded some psd templates that I must edit. In this case, I am attempting to continue the red bar across the black area that currently divides it. It is in bitmap form, however (no layer effects I can look at), so I'm wondering what the best way would be to make the red bar look like it seamlessly continues across this black gap?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm reading this wrong, the quickest way to do this is to just grab 1px of the area and stretch it out the whole length:

[image: Grab 1px]

[image: Streeeetch]

[image: Finished Result]

Comment: if you stretch the image and any imperfections will also be stretched with it.

Answer (score 2):

I would just zoom in and select the red color from the very bottom of the image, where it meets the thin red & black line. I'd create a large red rectangle in that color, covering the whole width of the page. Then I'd add a gradient overlay of black fading to transparent, with the black starting at the top and fading to transparent at the bottom. I'd make that whole overlay semi-transparent until I matched the original.

Comment: tldnr; don't match it, re-make it.

Comment: Hm, I'm trying this, but it's not really black fading to transparent - more dark red fading to lighter red...

Comment: Also, re:  "I'd make that whole overlay semi-transparent until I matched the original." Do you mean lowering the opacity of the new layer while continuing to tinker? I'm not sure how this would achieve the match, as making the layer semi-transparent would itself be altering it :(

Comment: Hi Zakgottlieb, I meant I'd lower the opacity of the gradient overlay. When you're in the Layer Style dialog box, right below Blend Mode is an opacity slider. It is set at 100% as a default. You can slide that down (or type a number) to reduce the opacity of the gradient so more of the original shape shows thru.

Answer (score 2):

- open in Photoshop
- 1 pixel width guide by however height it is
- use the rectangle Marquee Tool
- `Edit > Define Pattern`
- Rectangle Tool with Fill Pixels selected
- Right click on layer you just added the box
- Blending Options
- Choose the pattern you just made.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### It would better if you did this in code

to do this look up CSS3 gradients.  Some good examples here at [CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/) and here is a [generator](http://gradients.glrzad.com/).  Your code would look something like this for the gradient:

```
.linearBg2 {
  /* fallback */
  background-color: #1a82f7;
  background: url(images/linear_bg_2.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;

  /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1a82f7), to(#2F2727));

  /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

  /* Firefox 3.6+ */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

  /* IE 10 */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
}
```